# Vue returns [__ob__: Observer]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an API:

```
getFollowers(following) {
  return axios.post(`${options.serverUrl}/follower/get-followers`, {following})
},
```

And a component with this method:

```
created () {
  this.loadFollowers()
},
async loadFollowers () {
  const response = await services.getFollowers(this.$store.state.profile._id)
  console.log('followers', response)
  this.followers = response.data
},
```

Backend:

```
router.post('/follower/get-followers', (req, res) => {
  const query = {
    following: req.body.following
  }
  Follower.find(query)
    .populate('follower', 'firstname lastname avatar id _id')
    .then(result => res.send(result))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
})
```

The problem is that this method works correctly when the page hot-reloads (after saving changes), or when I open this component from `router-link`, but it doesn't work if I reload the page from the browser; it returns an empty array. I already tried all lifecycle hooks.

Comment: Is the service returning an empty array?

Comment: Yes. If I reaload page from borwser (ctrl+R, F5), response.data looks like [__ob__: Observer]. But if I just change something in component and save it, after hot reload I've got [{...}, __ob__: Observer], where {...} is expecting object.

Comment: It's impossible to determine the root cause from the question alone, and it seems like the issue is in the service (backend). Could it be an authentication problem? For example: on reload, your app isn't sending the appropriate headers perhaps because some auth token isn't available.

Comment: I updated the question with backend code. As you can see there is no special checks. By unknown reason, Vue doesn't wait for the end of the action and returns empty array .__.

Comment: have you tried `loadFollowers: async function ()` instead of `async loadFollowers ()`? https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3308

Comment: Guys I find it. This is stupid, but when I call method (after page reload) my store just isn't ready, so this.$store.state.profile._id = undefined. How to call method when store is ready?

Answer (score 2):

`[__ob__: Observer]` is normal to see when you have an array that is observed by Vue, that is also empty. Otherwise you will see something like `[__ob__: Observer, value1, value2]`.

What you are describing is that if you do your request to `services.getFollowers` on the first tick the application exists, you get an empty array, and if you do it later you get the correct response. This suggests that `this.$store.state.profile._id` is not what you expect it to be when starting the application.

I would suggest adding a `debugger` statement as the second line of `loadFollowers` and inspecting both the state and the network tab for whatever request was done. If you are restoring the state from somewhere, make sure that the state has been fully restored before your application can truly load (e.g. add a `v-if` on a router-view that is only true whenever the state has been restored). If you start from scratch, make sure that all mutations have been fired that you expect to be fired before this api call.

Comment: You are GOD savior. 
I've been trying for 3 days at work to solve it. Adding v-if="myarray.length > 0" solved my life. Thank youuuuuu!

Comment: TRULY YOU ARE A SAVIOR been searching the web for the whole day for this answer

Answer (score 0):

> when I call method (after page reload) my store just isn't ready, so `this.$store.state.profile._id = undefined`. How to call method when store is ready?

You could add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) that only calls `loadFollowers` when the store has a profile ID:

```
export default {
  watch: {
    '$store.state.profile._id': {
      immediate: true,
      handler(profileId) {
        if (profileId) {
          this.loadFollowers(profileId)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async loadFollowers (profileId) {
      const response = await services.getFollowers(profileId)
      ...
    }
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmyy46y748?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FFollowers.vue)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to wait for your `store` to be ready before calling `new Vue` in your main.

Or use `asyncComputed` to get your id.

Or use @tony19 solution to watch the store.